# calculating number of permutations (I guess)

Tags: math, statistics, permutation, combinations

I can generate word using 2 letters only, lets say 'k' and 'e'. Length of word is from 5 - 35 characters. Each letter and len of the word are randomly chosen with rand(). Can someone tell me how much possible unique words I can produce.
Thanks.

PS are these called permutations or combinations?

Comment: `2^5+2^6+...+2^35` = `2^36 - 2^5`

Comment: These are neither combinations nor permutations, and you haven't asked a programming question.

Comment: well I saved you guys from coding... i made generator myself ;)

Comment: @Matt - They are permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permutations: order matters (your case)
Combinations: order does not matter, i.e. "ke" == "ek"

N = 2^5 + 2^6 + ... 2^34 + 2^35

This is a finite-length geometric series, and Wolfram Alpha tells us:
Sum[2^k, {k, 5, 35}]
68719476704
68,719,476,704 == some 69 billion

Comment: Actually I am too rusty to tell you the correct term, it is not "Combinations".  It may be "Permutations", "Variations" or something else.

Answer (score 1):

For each word of length N: there are 2 choices for each letter, thus there are 2<sup>n</sup>  possible words. Adding up these values for all word lengths from 5 to 35:

```
>>> sum(2**n for n in range(5,36))
68719476704L
```

Comment: This shows the number of possible combinations given the 2 letters.  26*25*your_answer gives total unique possibilities...I think.

Comment: @prelic: I don't see how you're getting 26*25*68719476704.

Comment: Specifically, answers of the form `product(N...N-1...)` assume permutations *without replacement* which is why the number goes down each time. We aren't working with a fixed bag of letters here.

Comment: Assuming there are 26 letter possibilities for the first letter, and 25 for the second (don't want to overcount the strings that are all the same).  Your answer is the total number of unique possibilities given

Comment: there are 2 possibilities for the first letter, `k` and `e`. Ditto for the second letter. I don't understand where the 26 comes from.

Comment: I'm just saying you're interpreting that the letters must either be `k` or `e`, and that `k` and `e` weren't just examples.  My calculation was for the total number of unique 2-distinct-letter words, given any two distinct letters from the alphabet.